# How to perform 2 transfers at once using cleos push transaction?

Tags: cleos, transactions

I've searched for the answer on Google to no avail.

I am able to use `cleos transfer` 2 run the following transactions without an error:

```
cleos -u <eos ny api url> transfer abcabcabcabc cbacbacbacba '12 EOS' 'action:bet,gameId:122345,item:player,ref:efggfeefggfe'
cleos -u <eos ny api url> transfer abcabcabcabc cbacbacbacba '25 EOS' 'action:bet,gameId:122345,item:player,ref:efggfeefggfe'
```

Could someone explain how to use `cleos push transaction` to combine those 2 transfers into one?
This would help so as not to have to call cleos repeatedly and just call it once.

Comment: You need to make a abi action that call `cbacbacbacba` twice. And you have to pass those parameters to that abi action. And  inside your new abi action passed those parameters to your `cbacbacbacba` action. Other wise transfering two transaction using cloes is not possible at same time there should be some  delta T time between two transactions

Answer (score 1):

## Cleos Method

You can do it with `cleos` by creating the json for each transfer, as follows:

```
cleos transfer from_account, to_account quantity memo -s -d -j
```

Flags:

```
-s,--skip-sign              Specify if unlocked wallet keys should be used to sign transaction
-d,--dont-broadcast         don't broadcast transaction to the network (just print to stdout)
-j,--json                   print result as json
```

This creates json output do this for all the transfers you want to do it for, it should look like this:

```
{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:37",
    "ref_block_num": 92,
    "ref_block_prefix": 276911189,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0040c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}

{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:42",
    "ref_block_num": 102,
    "ref_block_prefix": 3271438144,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0080c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}

{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:45",
    "ref_block_num": 109,
    "ref_block_prefix": 718898287,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d00c0c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}
```

To make this into one transaction, copy and paste each of the actions into the first json output, as follows:

```
{
  "expiration": "2018-10-20T10:54:37",
    "ref_block_num": 92,
    "ref_block_prefix": 276911189,
    "max_net_usage_words": 0,
    "max_cpu_usage_ms": 0,
    "delay_sec": 0,
    "context_free_actions": [],
    "actions": [{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0040c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    },{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d0080c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    },{
      "account": "eosio.token",
      "name": "transfer",
      "authorization": [{
        "actor": "fromaccount",
        "permission": "active"
      }
      ],
      "data": "00f2d4142123e95d00c0c85353840ccd102700000000000004454f5300000000046d656d6f"
    }
    ],
    "transaction_extensions": [],
    "signatures": [],
    "context_free_data": []
}
```

Finally, save this json file, and execute it as follows:

```
cleos push transaction ./test.json
```